# Dropping empty DataFrame partitions in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to repartition a DataFrame according to a column the the DataFrame has `N` (let say `N=3`) different values in the partition-column `x`, e.g:

```
val myDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,1,2,2,3,3)).toDF("x") // create dummy data
```

What I like to achieve is to repartiton `myDF` by `x` without producing empty partitions. Is there a better way than doing this?

```
val numParts = myDF.select($"x").distinct().count.toInt
myDF.repartition(numParts,$"x")
```

(If I don't specify `numParts` in `repartiton`, most of my partitions are empty (as `repartition` creates 200 partitions) ...)

Comment: According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options, the 200 partitions will be created because of default value for the config option `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`

Comment: Answer could be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854818/spark-dataframe-repartition-number-of-partition-not-preserved?noredirect=1#comment70893687_41854818

Answer (score 9):

I'd think of solution with **iterating over `df` partition and fetching record count in it** to find non-empty partitions.

```
val nonEmptyPart = sparkContext.longAccumulator("nonEmptyPart") 

df.foreachPartition(partition =>
  if (partition.length > 0) nonEmptyPart.add(1))
```

As we got non-empty partitions (`nonEmptyPart`), we can clean empty partitions by using `coalesce()` ([check coalesce() vs repartition()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce)).

```
val finalDf = df.coalesce(nonEmptyPart.value.toInt) //coalesce() accepts only Int type
```

It may or may not be the best, but this solution **will avoid shuffling as we are not using `repartition()`**

---

## Example to address comment

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)).toDF("x").repartition($"x")
val nonEmptyPart = sc.longAccumulator("nonEmptyPart")

df1.foreachPartition(partition =>
  if (partition.length > 0) nonEmptyPart.add(1))

val finalDf = df1.coalesce(nonEmptyPart.value.toInt)

println(s"nonEmptyPart => ${nonEmptyPart.value.toInt}")
println(s"df.rdd.partitions.length => ${df1.rdd.partitions.length}")
println(s"finalDf.rdd.partitions.length => ${finalDf.rdd.partitions.length}")
```

**Output**

```
nonEmptyPart => 3
df.rdd.partitions.length => 200
finalDf.rdd.partitions.length => 3
```

Comment: `val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,1,2,2,3,3)).toDF("x").repartition(10, $"x")‌​.coalesce(3)`. Now it narrow downs number of partitions from 10 to 3.

Comment: and now do `finalDf.foreachPartition(p => println(p.size))`. I get `0 0 6`, i.e. 2 partitions are empty, 1 contains all the rows. Thats not what I wanted (I'm uisng Spark 1.6.3)

Comment: It could be because of shuffling disabled with `coalesce`. Try using `repartition`, it will shuffle all the data according to the `HashPartitioner`. so there will be a chance of every partition will be filled up with some data. If you really strict about removing empty partitions you may need run it(**finding non empty partitions and applying coalesce/repartition**) iterativly.